Can I detach the kitchen sprayer and leave it off?
Can I detach the sprayer from the kitchen sink and leave it off, or do I have to put the sprayer back on? Is there a cap you have to put on it?

If you detach the sprayer you will have an open hose with water pressure behind it whenever the faucet is on.  Cap at the faucet with whatever size fitting it uses.  You can take it off when the faucet is off and take it to the hardware store to get the right size.  Just trace the line back to the faucet.

If yer lucky. Some faucets do not have removable sprayer hoses, or use some proprietary method of attachment that would take a deal of macgyvering to replace.
